# Почему не выполняется блок else?

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть хэндлер, который "прослушивает" нажатие inline-кнопок
В БД есть столбец battle_use_check и функция, которая возвращает его значение - db.battle_use_check(chat_id)
Я пытаюсь сделать проверку: Если battle_use_check == 0, то регистрируем, если 1 - соответственно, не регистрируем пользователя!
Первое условие выполняется, но блок else отказывается работать!
По умолчанию battle_use_check принимает значение равное 0

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains="create_room_battle")
async def create_room_battle(call: CallbackQuery):
    message_id = call.from_user.id
    chat_id = call.message.chat.id

    battle_use_check = db.battle_use_check(chat_id) #флаг: если состоит в комнате - 1; если нет - 0

    if int(battle_use_check) == 0:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Done', parse_mode="HTML")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, f' <b>Невозможно создание новой комнаты!\n'
                                        f' Ты уже состоишь в одной батл-комнате!\n', parse_mode="HTML")
    await call.answer()
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что *battle_use_check* вообще принимает ненулевое значение? Я, например, не вижу здесь регистрации нового состязания в случае, если оно еще не создано. Добавьте вывод перед `if/else`, может выясните что-то новое

Comment: По умолчанию battle_use_check принимает значение равное 0

Comment: А почему вы тогда ожидаете, что код попадет в ветку `else`? Вы ведь сами пишете, что для нулевых значений предназначена ветка с сообщением об успехе

Comment: Если пользователь создал комнату, то battle_use_check меняется на 1, поэтому попадание в блок else может быть

Comment: Посмотрите на мое первое сообщение - либо вы предоставили не весь код, либо действительно нигде не меняете *battle_use_check* на 1

Comment: Удивительно, что когда я вывожу в консоль battle_use_check, вижу 1, но блок else все равно не исполняется! Уже смотрел на тип переменной - везде int

Comment: В таком случае, проблема не воспроизводится: https://onlinegdb.com/gsmHiMeXp Могу только посоветовать внести отладочный вывод внутрь блока `else`

Comment: Представьте! Ошибка была в том, что у меня в блоке else (в выводе сообщения) был открыт тег <b>, но по невнимательности я его не закрыл! Поэтому и происходила ошибка! Я отдельно запустил этот кусок и вот, что мне вывелось: Can't parse entities: can't find end tag corresponding to start tag b. Спасибо вам большое за помощь!